# remove vertical empty space when div floating

Tags: html, css

It is my fault, I am trying to re-ask the question.

I have some code like this:

```
<style>
    div { 
        float: left; width: 150px; padding: 10px; 
        margin: 10px; color: #fff;
    }
</style>
<div style="background: #c33">
    a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a
</div>
<div style="background: #3c3;">
    b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>
    b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b
</div>
<div style="background: #33c;">
    c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c
</div>
<div style="background: #399;">
    d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>
</div>
<div style="background: #939;">
    e<br>e
</div>
<div style="background: #993;">
    f<br>f<br>f<br>f<br>f
</div>
<!--
      ... and so on ...
-->
```

when my visitor's screen has enough width, it is works fine like this.

[image: big screen]

when the screen become smaller, it still works fine at beginning.

[image: smaller]

but good time doesn't last long, when continually shrink screen size, it displayed like this.

[image: continually smaller]

some space appeared between `c(the blue one)` and `e(the purple one)`.

[image]

then `a(the red one)` and `f(the yellow one)`.

when shrink to 2 columns, `a` `c` and `e` are totally separated.

So, my question is, every my block have certain(fixed) width, uncertain(fluid) height, there is no max-width of this "block area" or say "the parent node of these blocks" or container whatever.

Can I just remove these unnecessary spaces using pure css way?

Hope this time I explained clearly, and thank you for reading my post.

Comment: There are many ways. CSS provides columns, grid layout, flex box layout, etc..

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I've tried many ways including `flex` and `column-count`, however in my situation none of them works just because my column number isn't fix. It depends on visitor's screen resolution.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include what you've tried and why it doesn't work for you. If you don't provide limitations, you'll just get a bunch of answers that you can't use. See [ask].

Comment: I'll try, thank you for the help.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I've edited my post, is this clear?

Comment: Sure. Honestly, if I were you, I'd look for a tutorial on "responsive web design", or just search SO.

Comment: @mike-mccaughan I am trying, but so huge a topic "responsive web design" is. I've tried "flex" and "media-queries with column-count", just doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

You might try to left float only two, and float right the other:

```css
.aaa,
.bbb,
.ccc {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

.bbb {
  float: right;
}

.aaa,
.ccc {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="aaa" style="background: #933">
  a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a
</div>
<div class="bbb" style="background: #393">
  b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br> b
  <br>b<br>b<br>b<br>bbr>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b
</div>
<div class="ccc" style="background: #339">
  c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Grid, flex... and even simply using floats and clears:

```html
<style>
    div { 
        width: 200px; padding: 10px; 
        margin: 20px; color: #fff; 
    }
</style>
<div style="background: #933; float: left;">
    a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a
</div>
<div style="background: #393; float:right;">
    b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>
    b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b
</div>
<div style="background: #339; clear:left;">
    c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Which I want to done is when visitor's screen is big enough, there are four five or six blocks display in one line, when they reduce screen size, blocks split into 2 rows, if there are six blocks then it is a 5 column 2 rows display. when they continue reduce screen, page will become 4 columns 2 rows, 3 columns 2 rows then 2 columns 3 rows. well, am I explain clear?

Comment: @NotUser9123 well, that's not what you asked... Please edit and be more specific, including that "detail", and if the height of the items is fixed or fluid, if they should expand / shrink in width / height, it they should keep some sort of order, if for whatever reason you want to avoid media queries, etc.

Comment: Is it better to edit my question or just delete it and re-ask? thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: I've edited my question, is this time my question clear?

Comment: @NotUser9123 much clearer now. I'll edit the anser as well. Do you need to keep the elements in a certain order?

Comment: It is cool if they can keep order, however they don't have to. after all the biggest monster I am facing to are these spaces.

Answer (score 1):

To some extent you can do that, if you use left AND right floats as shown below and put a wrapper around it to let the right-floated elements not go too far right:

```css
div {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}

.a {
  float: left;
}

.b {
  float: right;
}
.wrapper {
width: 520px;)
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div style="background: #933" class="a">
    a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a
  </div>
  <div style="background: #393" class="b">
    b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br> b
    <br>b<br>b<br>b<br>bbr>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b
  </div>
  <div style="background: #339" class="a">
    c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Like others have said, there are plenty ways of doing it, but I'd use flexbox.

Just wrap the two boxes on the left in a container div, and use display:flex on that container, and set the flex-direction property to column and they should stack on top of one another.

Here's a great website to pick up the basics - http://flexboxfroggy.com/

Answer (score 1):

Oddly enough, the closest you could get is using damn CSS columns.. 
Yeah, that's right. I just said "CSS Columns"

Declaring an auto column layout using your divs width as column width, and making sure no div will wrap into multiple columns with `break-inside: avoid;` you can get pretty close.

```
  body {
    columns: 150px;
    column-gap: 2em;
  }
  div { 
    break-inside: avoid;
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p0yLs5sh/1/

And yes, I know. I just said columns. Thought that would never be an answer.